# The type java.lang.Charsequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required.class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I know this question was asked on here but it was related to something different. This is my program, I had to create my own class.  Also, when I try to use the system.out.printf () function, it doesnt work how come?  Thank you, from a very lost beginner programmer. :

```
public class IDInfo {
public static void main(String[] args){
}




private double name;
private double studentID;
private double Major;
private double CreditsNeeded;
private double CreditsTaken;

String getName = "Alex Wilson";
String getID = "916183391";
String getMajor1 = "Biochemistry";
String getCreditsNeeded = "128";
String getCreditsTaken = "14";


public void setname ( double name  )
{
    name = name; 
}

public void setstudentID (double ID)
{
    studentID = ID;

}

public void setMajor (double Major)
{
    Major=Major;

}

public void setCreditsNeeded (double CreditsNeeded)
{
    CreditsNeeded=CreditsNeeded;

}

public void setCreditsTaken (double CreditsTaken)
{
    CreditsTaken=CreditsTaken;

}

public double getName()
{
    return name;

}

public double getID ()
{
    return studentID;

}

public double getMajor ()
{
    return Major;

}

public double getCreditsNeeded ()
{
    return CreditsNeeded;
}

public double getCreditsTaken ()
{
    return CreditsTaken;

}

public double getCreditsRemaining ()
{
    return CreditsNeeded - CreditsTaken;
}
{



}}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't help that you haven't shown the code which apparently fails - but you've shown a lot of unrelated code. Please show a short but complete program (and properly formatted) demonstrating the problem - and ideally, look up Java naming conventions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a case sensitive language, so make sure your references are correct. I would also suggest reading about the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), as what you have shown is very inconsistent.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems with the compiler. If you are using jdk 8, I would suggest rolling back compiler to jdk 7 and rebuild the code.

Some more places to consider -

If you are using any of the following release of eclipse

Helios doesn't support Java 8 at all. Kepler doesn't support it by default.
But eclipse have released patch for the same.

[Kepler Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/)